# React Project is different on localhost and on website (letterSpacing)

Tags: css, reactjs, localhost, web-deployment, letter-spacing

While I was working on localhost the site seems okay for me but when I deployed the project into a website letterSpacing seems a bit increasing. I did not changed anything while deploying.

There are two images, first one shows the localhost and the second one shows the deployed website.

Most of the letters are broken but some of them still looks like the localhost version. I checked the problems with red and checked the normal strings as blue.
[image: LocalHost]
[image: DeployedWebsite]

Comment: Inspect the code on the live site to see where the letter spacing is coming from.

Comment: Browser extensions doesn't work on localhost. 
Check your extensions